# невозможно безопасно скачать файл

Tags: http, google-chrome

Был ряд анонсов, в которых говорилось, что Google запретит Chrome скачивать файлы по HTTP ([пример](https://www.ixbt.com/news/2020/02/08/snova-razdrazhajushie-blokirovki-google-zapretit-chrome-skachivat-vsjo-podrjad.html)).

Вижу блокировку в действии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Беглым взглядом не вижу в сети пояснений. Понимаю, что правильное решение — переход на HTTPS, но, быстрый переход на HTTPS невозможен.

Есть какой-то список рекомендаций что может быть скачано, а что не может быть скачано? Что должно быть в архиве? Можно ли скачивать ZIP, можно ли в ZIP класть документы CSV, XLS, DOC, TXT?

Comment: «быстрый переход на https невозможен» — у вас было пять лет на это...

Comment: И насчёт анонсов — вроде с Chrome 86 (а это уже в ближайший месяц) собираются запретить скачивать вообще любые файлы по http, так что заморачиваться со «списком рекомендаций» уже нет практического смысла https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/ad8/a52/1bd/ad8a521bd3c5d2dfaa89f850f651fcb9.png

Comment: Оставлю это тут: [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)